# AWS Managed updates overwrites local files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS beanstalk to host one of my application.
My application saves local configuration files constantly into .property and .csv files.
Everything works fine.

Till one day I noticed everything has been rolled back to the initial state:
The application is working fine but all the configurations I entered into .property and the history I saved into .csv are disappeared.

I looked at the beanstalk instant history and noticed that AWS implemented an update to the instance as the following. I guess when AWS implements the system maintenance it simply redeploy the application with the last .zip file I uploaded for the application deployment.

I know I can create a database to persist all the data I entered, however, that will be a big change.

Another option (which I am using right now) is to simply turn off the Managed updates feature. But my instance might slowly be faded out due to constant updates and patches nowadays.

Any idea how can I keep the managed updates open but instead of using the last .zip file to deploy the application, use the current working directory (I assume it is /app directory) after the update?

At the following is what happened during AWS managed updates:

```
2022-08-12 23:15:46 UTC+1000    
INFO
Environment update completed successfully.
2022-08-12 23:15:46 UTC+1000    
INFO
Successfully deployed new configuration to environment.
2022-08-12 23:14:38 UTC+1000    
INFO
Updating environment xxx-env's configuration settings.
2022-08-12 23:14:30 UTC+1000    
INFO
Environment update is starting.
2022-08-12 07:13:20 UTC+1000    
INFO
Environment health has transitioned from Info to Ok. Configuration update completed 83 seconds ago and took 11 minutes.
2022-08-12 07:12:37 UTC+1000    
INFO
Environment update completed successfully.
2022-08-12 07:12:37 UTC+1000    
INFO
Successfully deployed new configuration to environment.
2022-08-12 07:12:21 UTC+1000    
INFO
Removed instance [i-025394c6b5dc] from your environment.
2022-08-12 07:09:09 UTC+1000    
INFO
Deployment succeeded. Terminating old instances and temporary Auto Scaling group.
2022-08-12 07:07:50 UTC+1000    
INFO
Updating environment xxx-env's configuration settings.
2022-08-12 07:07:20 UTC+1000    
INFO
Waiting for post-deployment configuration to complete.
2022-08-12 07:07:16 UTC+1000    
INFO
Instance deployment completed successfully.
2022-08-12 07:06:39 UTC+1000    
INFO
Starting post-deployment configuration on new instances.
2022-08-12 07:06:11 UTC+1000    
INFO
Attached new instance(s) to the permanent auto scaling group awseb-e-wiuxjqswqj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-AV.

2022-08-12 07:06:07 UTC+1000    
INFO
Detached new instance(s) from temporary auto scaling group awseb-e-wiuxjqswqj-immutable-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1I2W.
2022-08-12 07:04:29 UTC+1000    
INFO
Waiting for instance(s) (i-0463ad18900a) to pass health checks. 
2022-08-12 07:03:21 UTC+1000    
INFO
Added instance [i-0463ad18900a] to your environment.
2022-08-12 07:03:21 UTC+1000    
INFO
Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Configuration update in progress on 1 instance. 0 out of 1 instance completed (running for 2 minutes). All instances are in same availability zone (us-west-2c).
2022-08-12 07:00:52 UTC+1000    
INFO
Created temporary auto scaling group awseb-e-wiuxjqswqj-immutable-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1I2.
2022-08-12 07:00:21 UTC+1000    
INFO
Immutable deployment policy enabled. Launching one instance with the new settings to verify health.
2022-08-12 07:00:13 UTC+1000    
INFO
Environment update is starting.
2022-08-12 07:00:11 UTC+1000    
INFO
Managed platform update is in-progress.
```

Answer (score 0):

> My application saves local configuration files constantly into .property and .csv files. Everything works fine.

Any deployment, auto-scaling event, managed update, or failed instance recovery may delete the files you are storing to the local Elastic Beanstalk disk. You could **never** write files to the local Elastic Beanstalk disk!

You should change your application to write data to a persistent database, or use an Elastic File System (EFS) volume to write your files to.